# Websites accessible but ping fails

Tags: networking, ping

I can access websites through a browser but all ping commands fail.

Tried running `ping` on Windows, Linux VM, Android (termux) but none of them worked.
Here is the output of `ping google.com`

```
Pinging google.com [2404:6800:4009:802::200e] with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 2404:6800:4009:802::200e:
    Packets: Sent = 2, Received = 0, Lost = 2 (100% loss)
```

This also happens with ip addresses, `ping 8.8.8.4` fails with request timed out.

All these commands used to work before.

If I use a VPN however, these commands start working again.

Any ideas what might have happened? Could this somehow be related to the ISP not allowing ping requests (idk if that's possible or not.)

Here is the output of `traceroute google.com` (with VPN):

```
traceroute to google.com (172.217.19.206), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  _gateway (10.0.2.2)  0.235 ms  0.551 ms  0.404 ms
 2  185.212.171.2 (185.212.171.2)  261.619 ms  266.395 ms  267.765 ms
 3  vlan30.bb1.ams1.nl.m247.com (185.212.171.1)  269.704 ms  270.161 ms  273.277  ms
 4  * * *
 5  217.138.223.232 (217.138.223.232)  273.055 ms  274.281 ms  274.576 ms
 6  vlan2921.pni1.ams2.nl.m247.com (83.97.21.26)  270.286 ms  194.534 ms  203.88 6 ms
 7  176.10.83.119 (176.10.83.119)  200.508 ms  192.516 ms  198.808 ms
 8  core1.ams.net.google.com (80.249.208.247)  206.728 ms  207.499 ms  207.396 m s
 9  108.170.241.225 (108.170.241.225)  207.784 ms  207.697 ms  207.610 ms
10  72.14.239.45 (72.14.239.45)  207.029 ms  207.383 ms  200.772 ms
11  ams16s31-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.19.206)  207.365 ms  207.836 ms  207.756  ms
```

`traceroute google.com` (without VPN):

```
traceroute to google.com (216.58.203.142), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  _gateway (10.0.2.2)  0.438 ms  0.328 ms  0.318 ms
 2  192.168.42.129 (192.168.42.129)  1.639 ms  0.975 ms  1.176 ms
 3  * * *
```

This stops at hop 2.

Thanks!

Comment: Does `ping -4 ...` work?

Comment: You don't really need IPv6 in the local network, so you can disable IPv6 and ensure IPv4 is enabled.

Comment: @DavidPostill no.

Comment: @harrymc ipv4 is enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [`traceroute`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/traceroute) to find out which hop on your path most likely is blocking [ICMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol) packets.

That you are able to `ping` the same hosts from your machine when using a VPN is a very strong indicator for your ISP - or someone else along the way - is blocking the ICMP requests or responses; yes, this is indeed possible.

Comment: Note that Linux traceroute will use UDP probes by default – you need to explicitly tell it to use ICMP Echo probes using `--icmp`.

Comment: @binary10 then this seems to be the correct answer, especially if this affects all devices in your local network. Try contacting your ISP then.

Comment: @acran accepted the answer. Is it normal for ISPs to block ICMP though?